# What are the geometric spaces / shapes that are spanned by vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm not sure if I'm wording the question correctly, but I am really confused by the shapes and stuff spanned by vectors. Like I know 1 LI(linearly independent) vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ spans a line, but 2 spans entire $\mathbb{R}^2$. 1 LI in $\mathbb{R}^3$ spans a line, 2 spans a plane, 3 spans $\mathbb{R}^3$. I think 0 vector spans a dot? But like what comes after? What about $\mathbb{R}^4$? What is 1 LI, 2 LI, 3 LI supposed to span? I know n will always span $\mathbb{R}^n$, but aside from that, I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Is the question about terminology? If so, the span of $k$ linearly independent vectors is a *$k$-plane*. A $0$-plane is a singleton containing the zero vector, a $1$-plane is a *line*, and a $2$-plane is sometimes just called a *plane*. If the vector space has finite dimension $n$, we can think of the space as an *$n$-plane*. For any $n > 0$, we can call a *$(n - 1)$-plane* a *hyperplane*.

Comment: I'm just wondering what n, n-1, n-2, etc linearly independent vectors in a set of n vectors would span in Rn. Say I have a set of 4 vectors in R4, but only 3 are linearly independent, what is it supposed to represent? A line? A plane? Something else?

Comment: It would by definition be a $3$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^4$.

Answer (score 1):

$n$ linearly independent vectors will always span a $n$ dimensional vector space

$\mathbb{R}^m$ is $m$ dimensional

You can have a $n$ dimensional subspace inside a $m$ dimensional vector space if $n<m$

Terminology (maybe? I’m not so sure), restrict our vector spaces to $\mathbb{R}^n$, then

A 1 dimensional vector space is called a line

A 2 dimensional vector space is called a plane

Idk what a 3 dimensional vector space is supposed to be, but you can think of it like our space in 3D / real life embedded inside a “bigger” 4D(?) space, but obviously our brain can’t imagine spaces over 4D, but we can still describe it using coordinates

$$
V=\text{Span}( \{(a,b,c,d),(e,f,g,h),(i,j,k,l) \}
$$

which doesn’t cover the entire $\mathbb{R}^4$